# AngularJS: Why doesn't $scope detect all objects?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I am developing a web application using AngularJS. I have a problem with the $scope object.
My application is made up of many HTML pages and there is one where I use a multitude of different `<form>` (Which are enabled in cascade with `ng-if`), like that:

```
<form name="formOne" class="form-alignment">
   <div>Elements of form...</div>
   <div>Elements of form...</div>
</form>

<div ng-if="someMethod()>
   <form name="formTwo" class="form-alignment">
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
   </form>
</div>

<div ng-if="someOtherMethod()>
   <form name="formThree" class="form-alignment">
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
   </form>
</div>
```

In the controller I use the `$scope` object to immediately understand when these forms are valid or invalid through the `$valid` property, using watches... like that:

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
            return $scope.formOne.$valid;
        }), function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if($scope.formOne.$valid == true) {
                console.log("First form valid")
            } else {
                console.log("First form invalid")
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately I don't understand why the `$scope` object **only detects the first form** and not all the others (even if they are displayed on the web page!). For example, if I print in the console the $scope object, the result is:

[image]

As you can see, only `formOne` (and therefore its `formOne.$valid`, `formOne.$invalid`, etc) properties are detected in the object, but no `formTwo` and `formThree`!
For example, if you wanted to use the property  `formOne.$valid` in a watch made as before, I obtain the following error:

[image]

Although this property exists and it is also possible to see it directly in the template by doing `{{formTwo.$valid}}` for example!

How is this problem solved? and why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because ng-if creates a child scope. In order to fix this you could use ng-show instead or put the forms in an object.

```
// controller
$scope.forms = {};

// view
<form name="forms.formOne" class="form-alignment">
    <div>Elements of form...</div>
   <div>Elements of form...</div>
</form>

<div ng-if="someMethod()>
   <form name="forms.formTwo" class="form-alignment">
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
   </form>
</div>

<div ng-if="someOtherMethod()>
   <form name="forms.formThree" class="form-alignment">
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
      <div>Elements of form...</div>
   </form>
</div>
```